# ORA-06550 wrong number or types of arguments when calling Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, stored-procedures

```
procedure select_card_transaction(trans_id   nvarchar2,
                                    usr_id    number,
                                    Quantity out number) is
  begin
    select count(*)
      into Quantity
      from user_cards u
     where u.transaction_id = trans_id
       and u.user_id = usr_id;
  end;
```

**and Consuming it:**

```
using(var conn = new OracleConnection(Settings.Default.OraWUConnString))
            { 
                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "for_temporary_testing.select_card_transaction";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;



                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("trans_id", TransactionID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("usr_id", UserID);

                var q = new OracleParameter("Quantity", OracleType.Number);
                q.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(q);
                //cmd.Parameters[0].OracleType = OracleType.NVarChar;
                //cmd.Parameters[1].OracleType = OracleType.Number; 

                conn.Open();
                var obj = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();
                return (int)q.Value == 1;
            }
```

It returns the following error.
ORA-06550 wrong number or types of arguments when calling Oracle stored procedure...
**ANY IDEA?**

Comment: You're not adding the parameter `q` to the command...

Comment: edit. I added but still the same problem

Comment: so....is the code you posted the ACTUAL code that you are executing?

Comment: yes! it is I've just  added cmd.Parameters.Add(q);

Comment: What is the NET type of TransactionID?

Comment: string..................

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft Oracle Client or the Oracle OTN bits?

Comment: Another option is to write this as a function that returns the Quantity.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem before. Are you using the ODP.Net drivers? I was able to solve the problem by adding the output parameter first. This needs to be done before the input parameters. In your case it would look like

```
 using(var conn = new OracleConnection(Settings.Default.OraWUConnString))
            { 
                conn.Open();

                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "for_temporary_testing.select_card_transaction";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // Return value parameter has to be added first !
                var Quantity = new OracleParameter();
                Quantity.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                Quantity.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(Quantity);

                //now add input parameters
                var TransID = cmd.Parameters.Add("trans_id", TransactionID);
                TransID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                TransID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;

                var UsrID = cmd.Parameters.Add("usr_id", UserID);
                UsrID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                UsrID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();
                return Convert.ToInt32(Quantity.Value);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the parameter. It was null and oracle returned error. I got that if argument is **null**, it should be sent as **DBNULL**